# How do i get the 2.5 to be subscript without changing the output of the brackets? ggplot axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, subscript

I have the following code for the y axis label in ggplot

```
y = bquote('PM2.5 ('*µg~m^-3*')')
```

I want the 2.5 to be subscript but can't figure out how whilst also keeping the part in the brackets how I want it.

I want the output in R on the y axis label to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
plot(1, 1, main = bquote('PM'[2.5]~'('*µg~m^-3*')'))
```

-output

[image]